# Что дает значение атрибута rel равное bookmark?

Tags: html, html5, ссылки, атрибуты

Что реально дает rel=bookmark? Например если написать ссылку ссылка. По описанию спецификации html5 так и не понял, что это будет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут `rel`, просто описывает ссылку, то есть обозначает что это за ссылка, что за документ на который она ведёт.
А именно `rel=bookmark` обозначает что эта ссылка является якорем и ведёт на какую-то точку в этом же документе.

И по сути она не чего не даёт, разве что поисковым системам, что эта ссылка постоянная, а обычным пользователям - не чего.